# How to obtain the QQ plot of a spline model R

Tags: r, plot, spline

I have a model that I've fitted using splines:

```
ssfit.3 <- smooth.spline(anage$lifespan ~ log(anage$Metabolic.by.mass), 
                         df = 3)
```

I'm trying to obtain the model diagnostics such as the residual plot and the QQ plot for this model. I know for a linear model you can do

```
plot(lm)
```

which outputs all the different plots. How can I do this with spline models since `plot(ssfit.3)` does not output the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the residuals and use `qqnorm()`/`qqline()`.

```r
example(smooth.spline) ## to get a model to work with
qqnorm(residuals(s2m))
qqline(residuals(s2m))
```